# changing bg color on hovering button with css

Tags: hover

I would like to change the bg color while hovering on button, but seems like it is not working. I tried different ways and also searched about it. However,I can not understand what is the problem here. Here is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="hover"> </div>
    <button id="button">Hover Me!</button>
```

*the CSS part*

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
  }

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #151b29;

    }

#button {
font-family: 'Mate SC', serif;
background: none;
border: 2px solid;
color: rgb(250, 196, 49);
padding: 15px;
word-spacing: 4px;
transition: .2s linear 0s;

}

#button:hover {
border-color: rgb(173, 51, 255);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
letter-spacing: 8px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(173, 51, 255, 1);
font-weight: 500;

}

#button:hover ~ #hover{
 background:white;
}
```

Thank you in advance.